# Чем грозит синглтон для БД?

Tags: php, singleton

Избавляясь от глобальных переменных, решил ссылаться на PDO объект через промежуточный статический метод.

Сейчас использование БД выглядит так:

```
# Установка соединения (срабатывает только в первый раз)
DB::set('host','db_name','login','pass');
# Получение PDO объекта для взаимодействия
DB::get();
```

В классах работающих с БД для уменьшения связанности создаю приватную статическую переменную которой присваиваю DB::get().
Рассчитываю на то, что в случае если способ получения PDO объекта изменится, мне придется сменить только значение этой самой переменной в каждом классе работающем с БД.

Чем плох такой подход и чем он грозит при разрастании проекта?
Имеет ли смысл заводить реестр если таких объектов станет больше двух-трех?

Comment: А не получится неких коллизий в данных, если вдруг у вас будет два и более класса, использующие этот объект, и выполняющие запросы к БД при работе одного класса с объектом(ами) другого? Ну то есть Класс1 производит некий запрос к БД через синглтон, в синглтоне есть какие-то данные, которые он планирует использовать далее, и в этот момент он обращается к Класс2, который тоже пытается через синглтон решить свои задачи, таким образом вмешиваясь в то, что еще не доделал Класс1.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko ну синглтон хранит только лишь PDO объект подключения. И возвращает только его.

Создание запроса к БД - это создание нового объекта. В случае с синглтоном это выглядит так: DB::get()->query('SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 100')->fetch()

Comment: Ну тогда как по мне никаких проблем не предвидится, вопрос исключительно в наглядности и понятности кода, но это вкусовщина.

Comment: Синглтон - это одна большая глобальная переменная, со всеми вытекающими. Класс-обертка для объекта PDO - первый шаг к Dependency Injection, конфиг-файлам, IoC-контейнерам, ORM, Фреймворкам, Symfony, Doctrine, Hibernate, Spring, ...

Comment: @TryCatch, я не понял: DB::set() вызывается автоматически при первом же DB::get()? Или же он вызывается единоразово вручную где-то в начале программы? И ещё: что будет, если повторно вызвать DB::set(), но с другими параметрами подключения? Подключение переустановится на новые параметры? Или ничего не произойдёт (проигнорируется)?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/334078/ вместо тысячи слов

Comment: Используйте постоянные подключения

Comment: @ArchDemon это всего лишь одна из точек зрения. Как и любой паттерн проектирования, синглтон надо уметь готовить и знать где и как применять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сложно сказать, чем грозит именно в вашем случае. Многие проблемы, связанные со статическими методами и синглтонами для маленьких проектов носят чисто теоретический характер, нежели практический.

Попробуем потеоретизировать.

**1. Что будет, если добавится ещё одна база данных?**

Придётся добавить некий новый статический класс `DB2` и соответствующие методы `DB2::set()` / `DB2::get()`. Соответственно, в классах, которые используют оба подключения, придётся добавлять новую статическую переменную.

**2. Что будет, если понадобится писать тесты для компонентов, использующих БД?**

Придётся полагаться на то, что где-то там внутри компонентов вызов `DB::get()` сработает правильно. Мы не будем иметь доступа к инстансу соединения с БД, чтобы заменить его каким-нибудь `fake-объектом` для отдельного тестового случая.

**3. Что будет, если добавится несколько других точек входа в код?**

Например, помимо основного сайта появятся: API для мобильных приложений, консольные демоны, админская часть, личный кабинет партнёров. В этом случае придётся при инициализации каждого приложения вызывать `DB::set()` с параметрами подключения. То есть множество приложений окажутся завязанными на один единый синглтон. Вместо этого хотелось бы иметь конфиг подключения, который независимо используется каждым приложением. Ведь гипотетически прослойка для подключения к БД в них может быть разная.

---

Можно, наверно, придумать ещё много кейсов, в которых всё это станет неудобным и негибким во время роста, но **будет ли именно ваша разработка расти таким образом?** Вполне возможно, что:

- у вас всегда будет одна база данных
- для бизнеса всегда будет нерентабельным написание тестов
- точка входа будет всегда одна (не планируется мобильных клиентов и прочих расширений)

В этом случае синглтон является быстрым и простым решением вашей задачи (централизовано хранить подключение к БД).